# How do intern'd strings behave between different threads and classloarders?

Tags: java, string, locking, thread-safety, classloader

In java's documentation it says that in the below example, the condition will be true:

```
String a = new String("ABC");
String b = new String("ABC");

if (a.intern() == b.intern())
{
 ....
}
```

I wanted to know, if that is still true when considering that `a` and `b` are defined in different `Threads`, or even different `ClassLoaders`?

This question rose when I needed an ability to synchronize a block that loads a certain configuration based on an entity's name, so I wanted to do something like:

```
synchronized (entityName.intern())
{
}
```

I'm not sure this is a good practice, so I'm probably not going to pursue this direction - but the question still interests me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on different *threads*, yes, the condition will be true.

If on different *class loaders*, I wouldn't count on the condition being true. (But are you really loading two copies of `String` using different class loaders?) The documentation says that `intern` is implemented within `String`, using its own cache. From the [`String#intern` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29):

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
>
> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately **by the class `String`.**

*(My emphasis)*

So if you somehow loaded the `String` class twice using different class loaders (I'm not sure how you would do that, but I bet there's a way), then the two `String` classes would each have its own cache — in *theory*. However, an implementation might not make that fine a distinction. `intern` is a native method in the Oracle JVM, using a symbol table implemented in C++. I haven't followed the logic through closely enough to see whether in the edge case you're talking about, the two instances of `String` in the same JVM would share the same symbol table or not. But at that point, we're looking at implementation, which could vary. The *documentation* suggests no, they wouldn't be the same string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - interning works across the whole JVM.

I would be very concerned about your execution environment if you were loading multiple versions of `java.lang.String` via different class loaders... interning would be the least of your worries.

Comment: You're sure it's JVM-wide, even if you (somehow) load `String` twice using two different class loaders?